# Question about C datatype and constant

Tags: c, variables, integer, constants

Greetings!
I was experimenting with C language till I encountered something very strange.
I was not able to explain myself the result shown below.

**The Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num = 4294967295U;
    printf("%u\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

**The Question:**

1.) As you see, I created an `int` which can hold numbers between  *-2147483648* to *2147483647*.

2.) When I assign the value *4294967295* to this variable, the IDE shows me a warning message during compilation because the variable overflowed.

3.) Due to curiosity I added a *U (unsigned)* behind the number and when I recompiled it, the compiler did not return any warning message.

4.) I did further experiments by changing the *U (unsigned)* to *L (long)* and *LL (long long)*. As expected, the warning message still persist for these two but not after I change it to *UL (unsigned Long)* and *ULL (unsigned long long)*.

5.) Why is this happening?

**The Warning Message :(For steps 2)**

```
warning #2073: Overflow in converting constant expression from 'long long int' to 'int'.
```

**The Warning Message:(For steps 4 *LL* & *L*)**

```
warning #2073: Overflow in converting constant expression from 'long long int' to 'long int'.
```

*And last, thanks for reading my question, your teachings and advices are much appreciated.*

Comment: I think you are looking for a description of promotion rules in C. When I google them, one of the links I find at the top has the title "Integral promotion: It doesn't have to be logical. It's the law". That's a very good summary, perhpas you can find the information you need in that article: http://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2007/10/05/integral-promotion-it-doesn-t-have-to-be-logical-it-s-the-law.aspx

Comment: First of all, an `int` is only guaranteed to hold values from -32767 to 32767. Your platform very likely offers wider `int`s, but this is unspecified behavior that you cannot rely on.

Comment: @Thom If you are going to be pedantic about it, the range an integral type can hold is **implementation-defined**, which is not the same notion as **unspecified**.

Comment: @Pascal: this is not about **integer promotions**, this is about the type of **integer constants**, which is at ISO C99 6.4.4.1 Semantics.

Comment: @caramel23: The code you posted is apparently not the code you were testing. The warning message you quoted talks about conversion from `long long int` to `long int`. The `long long int` is apparently the type you gave your constant by using a suffix `LL`. But where does `long int` come from? I don't see any `long int`s in your code. Are you sure that `num` was declared as `int` and not as `long int` at the time you got that warning message?

Comment: @AndreyT: `int` is the same as `long int` on 32-bit platforms i think

Comment: @Claudiu: While the range and the representation of `int` could easily be the same as that of `long int`, they are still different independent types. If the conversion is to `int`, the compiler cannot refer to at as conversion to `long int` (unless the compiler is broken).

Comment: @ninjalj Since the OP is first to bring up the `U`, `L`, .. suffixes, I assumed his question was about the assignment, but I was indeed confused: I meant "conversion", not "promotion". Which is simpler anyway. And the conversion to a signed type is probably implementation-defined (just guessing here).

Comment: @caramel23: if you're using gcc, you can specify the `-Wconversion` option to catch this (but, really, you don't want to: it catches many, many constructs used in many, many lines of code)

Comment: Sorry,i forgot to add in another warning message,i just edited it by  adding the other warning message

Comment: Yes i'm very sure about that,btw i'm using pelles C that support c99 standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, by default, the compiler assumes you're typing in signed integers. When you give it `4294967295`, that number doesn't fit into a 4-byte integer, so it uses an 8-byte integer to store it, instead. Then it has to do a lossy conversion (`long long`, AKA 8-byte, to `long`, AKA 4-byte), so it gives you a warning.

However, when you type `4294967295U`, it knows you want an unsigned integer. That number fits into a 4-byte unsigned integer, so it has type `long int`, and no lossy conversion is necessary. (You're not losing data by going from `unsigned long int` to `long int`, just mis-representing it.)

Comment: Sorry,i forgot to add in another warning message,i just edited it by adding the other warning message

Answer (score 6):

As per the ISO C99 standard, section 6.4.4.1 (**Integer Constants**), subsection **Semantics**, the type of an integer constant is the first type of the following table where the value can be represented:

```
                                    Octal or Hexadecimal
Suffix            Decimal Constant            Constant
none         int                    int
             long int               unsigned int
             long long int          long int
                                    unsigned long int
                                    long long int
                                    unsigned long long int

u or U       unsigned int           unsigned int
             unsigned long int      unsigned long int
             unsigned long long int unsigned long long int

l or L       long int               long int
             long long int          unsigned long int
                                    long long int
                                    unsigned long long int

both u or U  unsigned long int      unsigned long int
and l or L   unsigned long long int unsigned long long int

ll or LL     long long int          long long int
                                    unsigned long long int

both u or U  unsigned long long int unsigned long long int
and ll or LL
```

Particular implementations can have extended integer types that follow the same pattern as above.

Comment: Also in 6.3.1.3/3, it is stated "the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; the result is **implementation-defined**."

Comment: Sorry,i forgot to add in another warning message,i just edited it by adding the other warning message